# Undefined Language in Drupal Arrays disappears when logged in

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, undefined

I'm trying to access the data in the node array from a node template on my site.  When I am logged in this all works fine; however, as soon as I log out the array structure changes. After a little digging, I discovered it is because the 'und' array would appear whenever I logged out.

I tried lots of solutions such as using `[$node->language]`, trying to access the data via the `#items` array and using `field_get_items` with no avail. The only way I can get it to work in both cases is to check if 'und' exists in the way, which I find a bit clunky just to retrieve a simple boolean value, or other data point.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to access, but this will get field values based upon the language of the node being rendered.

Get the language of the node:

```
$node_language = field_language("node", $form["#node"], "field_YOUR_FIELD");
```

For Default Field Value:

```
$field_value = $form["field_YOUR_FIELD"][$node_language][0]["CHECK_ARRAY_FOR_VALUE"]["#default_value"];
```

For Saved Field Value:

```
$field_value = $form["#node"]->field_YOUR_FIELD[$node_language][0]["CHECK_ARRAY_FOR_VALUE"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this kind of behaviour happens for certain fields (not all) in node templates when I in page.tpl.php(!) for some testing purposes use

`dsm($node);`

(using the module Devel 7.x-1.5). If I take away that line, it works as expected again.